# Why is Unity's Tilemap.HasSyncTileCallback() causing lag spikes when setting tiles to a tilemap?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity's 2d tilemap system for my game and its been working fabulously for old versions of the game. In this new version, I generate chunks that are 20x20 when the player is moving as the world is procedurally generated. Everything is very performant except when I am setting the tiles. When I do this I get Tilemap.HasSyncTileCallback() in my profiler and it extremely expensive causing my system to spike to around a couple frames and generates some garbage. Is there a way around this?

The functions I am calling are these

`terrainMap.SetTile(tempVect, StaticDatabase.database.Tiles[chunk.tiles[i, j].tileIDs[0]]);
terrainMap.SetTileFlags(tempVect, TileFlags.None);
terrainMap.SetColor(tempVect, chunk.tiles[i, j].tileColors[0]);`

I also ran the code with just the SetTile function and still had bad performance.

An idea I had to fix this was to stop the callback and refresh during these changes then call it manually to stop it from updating for each call, but I don't know how to even access these parameters.

Currently, I use unity's tile system for the graphics and colliders as I have my own implementation of the tiles in the form of "MyTile". Should I just stop using unity's tile system and try other methods such as object pooling or texture bombing?

Two sources one with the same problem
https://forum.unity.com/threads/settile-is-slow-plans-to-implement-ecs-pattern-to-tilemap.639619/

Another with Texture Bombing
https://forum.unity.com/threads/tile-map-accelerator-high-performance-shader-based-tile-map-renderer.708413/

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after testing multiple different methods. Calling SetTile() in a large loop of any kind has a high-performance cost. There is another method you can call if you need to place a lot of tiles such as SetTileBlock(). This avoids those Tilemap.TileSyncCallbacks and refreshTile() or, at least, keeps them at a minimum.

Heres my code for what I did to fix this in my question above.

```
public void loadTerrainFromChunk(MyChunk chunk)
    {
        Tile[] terrainTiles = new Tile[chunkSize * chunkSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < chunkSize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < chunkSize; j++)
            {
                Vector3Int tempVect = new Vector3Int(chunk.tiles[i, j].index.x, chunk.tiles[i, j].index.y, 0);
                int tempIndex = i + (j * chunkSize);
                if (chunk.tiles[i, j].tileIDs[0] != -1)
                {
                    terrainTiles[tempIndex] = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance("Tile") as Tile;
                    terrainTiles[tempIndex].sprite = StaticDatabase.database.Tiles[chunk.tiles[i, j].tileIDs[0]].sprite;
                    terrainTiles[tempIndex].name = StaticDatabase.database.Tiles[chunk.tiles[i, j].tileIDs[0]].name;
                    Matrix4x4 matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 90f * seededRandom.Next(3)), Vector3.one);
                    terrainTiles[tempIndex].transform = matrix;
                    terrainTiles[tempIndex].flags = TileFlags.None;
                    terrainTiles[tempIndex].color = chunk.tiles[i, j].tileColors[0];

                }
            }
        }

        terrainMap.SetTilesBlock(new BoundsInt(chunk.index.x*chunkSize, chunk.index.y*chunkSize, 1, chunkSize, chunkSize, 1), terrainTiles);

    }
```

All you need to do is

1) Make an array to hold your tiles.

2) Create Instances of the tiles you want and load them into the array.

3) (Optional) Modify the tiles in that array.

4) Load that array into the SetTilesBlock() function.

Have a good day!